# Getting specific values from a JSON file and put it through to specific fields in an existing YAML file

Tags: python, json, yaml, pyyaml

This is the JSON file, `vip5.json`.

```json
{
 "App Name": "test", 
 "Email": "test@test.com", 
 "Employee ID": "abc", 
 "Load Balancing Method": "Ratio", 
 "Network": "CMN", 
 "Pool Member": "pucq", 
 "Pool Monitor": "tcp", 
 "Pool name": "pool", 
 "SSL": "Required", 
 "VIP Name": "vs"
}
```

This is the YAML file `test.yaml`.

```yaml
---
server: pucl-k-030.company.com

partition: Common


nodes:
  - host: 10.74.204.75
    name: node-puex-spi-109
    description: PUEX1
    monitors:
      - /Common/icmp

  - host: 10.74.204.76
    name: node-puex-spi-110
    description: PUEX2 
    monitors:
      - /Common/icmp

pool:
  name: pool-puex-indexers
  descriptions: PUEX Indexers pool
  lb_method: 
  monitors:
    - /Common/tcp


pool_members:
  - node_name: node-puex-109
    port: 9997

  - node_name: node-puex-110
    port: 9997

virtual_server:
  name: vs-ng-puex-test-frwd
  destination: 1.1.1.1
  ip_protocol: udp
  port: 999
  type: performance-l4
  profiles:
    - name: fastL4 
  pool: pool-puex-indexers
```

I want to get these values and add it in certain fields in my YAML file. Let's say i want to get the value of `Ratio` from **"Load Balancing Method:"** in the JSON file and put that in the **"lb_method:"** in the YAML file. How do I do that?

I tried to read the JOSN file and iterate through the file. But I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

```
import json
import requests
import yaml

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/vip5.json"
r = requests.get(url)
json_file = json.loads(r.content)

print(json_file)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to Python! In a case like this where you have a bunch of key-value data, it's best to read in both documents as `dict` objects that can be easily compared. Here's a solution for what you described.

```
import json
import yaml

# Load files as dicts
with open('vip5.json', 'r') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
with open('test.yaml', 'r') as f:
    y = yaml.load(f)
# Assign JSON "Load Balancing Method" to YAML "lb_method".
y['pool']['lb_method'] = j['Load Balancing Method']
print(y)
```

You can elaborate on this to build the specific mapping you want. Does that help?

Comment: Thank You Legend! That works. I'll try assigning all the values i need and let you know :)